# RuntimeException - Session store not set on request - Laravel Socialite - Facebook

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, laravel-socialite, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` and `Laravel/Socialite 3.1`.

I want to login using a `Facebook` app I just configured for this project.

These are the main files I have configured for this:

**/.env**

```
...
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=***
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=***
FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback
```

**/config/services.php**

```
<?php

return [
    ...
    'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL'),

    ],
];
```

**/routes/api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

Route::get('auth/facebook', 'SocialiteController@redirectToProviderFacebook');
Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', 'SocialiteController@handleProviderCallbackFacebook');
```

**/app/Http/Controllers/SocialiteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Socialite;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProviderFacebook()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallbackFacebook()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        print_r($user->token);
    }
}
```

My problem is that for some reason I get the error:

```
RuntimeException
Session store not set on request.
```

as you can see on the following image:

[image]

I don't want to use sessions on this project at all. I just want to get the `token` from `Facebook` on the callback inside: `function handleProviderCallbackFacebook()`.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Socialite [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/socialite#stateless-authentication)

> The stateless method may be used to disable session state verification. This is useful when adding social authentication to an API:

`return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();`