# How to login user with Laravel Socialite (LinkedIn)

Tags: php, laravel-5, linkedin-api, laravel-socialite

I'm getting user Information after sign in LinkedIn with laravel Socialite package. I'm using lumen, after confirming the permissions from login screen it's giving me error. Although I have set my default guard to session in auth.php file. Error

```
RuntimeException 
Session store not set on request.
```

in my services.php  i'm using linkedIn provider

```
'linkedin' => [
'client_id' => 'dafasdfads',
'client_secret' => 'adsfadsfas',
'redirect' => 'http://myapp.temp/callback/linkedin'
],
```

My routes.php

```
$router->get('/redirect/{provider}', 'socialcontroller@redirect');
$router->get('/callback/{provider}', 'socialcontroller@callback');
```

My Controller file is

```
public function callback($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
}
```

Comment: I think you need look this link : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Comment: not working already tried

Comment: maybe this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917631/runtimeexception-session-store-not-set-on-request-laravel-socialite-facebo